# Content is cutting if it doesn't fit inside the page, jspdf. How to show content in another page?

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf

I'm using jspdf in angular. I'm generating the pdf on my .ts (I'm not using html).

I'm printing on my document the contents of an array of objects I get from my API.

Problem is that, when the contents on the array doesn't fit on the page, the contents get cut. I tried adding a new page but the page is blank.

Here's my method:

```
onNewReporte() {
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    const pageWidth =
      doc.internal.pageSize.width || doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    // let imgData = this.logo();
    const pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.height;

    //nombre paciente
    const pacienteInfo = this.consultas.map(a => a.pacienteId);
    const pacienteObj = pacienteInfo[0];
    const pacienteArray = Object.values(pacienteObj);
    const pacienteName = pacienteArray[2];

    //nombre guardian
    const guardian = pacienteArray[1];

    //formato fecha
    var options = { year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric" };

    //El pdf
    doc.setFontType("bold");
    doc.text("Historial de Consultas Médicas", pageWidth / 2, 75, "center");
    doc.setFontType("normal");
    doc.setFontSize(14);
    doc.text(
      "Paciente: " + pacienteName + "       Guardian: " + guardian,
      pageWidth / 2,
      90,
      "center"
    );
    doc.setFontSize(12);

    doc.line(20, 95, 190, 95);

    for (var i = 0; i < this.consultas.length; i++) {
      if (this.consultas[i] != null) {
        doc.text("Consulta N° " + (i + 1), 30, 110 + 75 * i);
        doc.text(
          "Fecha: " +
            new Date(this.consultas[i].fecha)
              .toLocaleDateString("es", options)
              .toString(),
          30,
          120 + 75 * i
        );
        doc.text("Motivo: " + this.consultas[i].motivo, 30, 130 + 75 * i);
        doc.text(
          "Pruebas a realizar: " + this.consultas[i].pruebas,
          30,
          140 + 75 * i
        );
        doc.text(
          "Observaciones: " + this.consultas[i].observaciones,
          30,
          150 + 75 * i
        );
        doc.text(
          "Diagnóstico: " + this.consultas[i].diagnostico,
          30,
          160 + 75 * i
        );
        doc.text(
          "Tratamiento: " + this.consultas[i].tratamiento,
          30,
          170 + 75 * i
        );
        //separacion
      }

      if (this.consultas.length > 2) {
        doc.addPage();
      }
    }
    //separacion

    doc.save(pacienteName + ".pdf");
  }
```

I've been googling to find something that could help me but I realize jspdf without using html2canvas or something like that has minimal documentation. I couldnt' find any linebreaks or page splits so I'm literally in blank right here.

Answer (score 1):

It's really late i guess but i resolved this with something like

> ```
> const doc = new jsPDF(jsPDFConfig);
> const x = 20;
> let y = 40;
> ```

Adding to (Y) on every line like this

> ```
> doc.setFontSize(10);
> doc.setFontStyle('bold');
> doc.text(this.clinicName, x, y);
> y += 12;
> ```

Later check with this and adding a page an restarting (Y)

> ```
> if (y + 20 > (PAGE HEIGHT)) {
>     doc.addPage();
>     y = 40;
>   }
> ```

The page height in my case is 841.89 from "a4" format. But you can try to get from doc.